# table column width by content but not more the 50%

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, col

Good day.
I have table with 2 columns: the first one for labels and the second one for control elements. Labels could be short and very long.

```css
table{
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

td{ border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td class="first-column">very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very label</td>
      <td class="second-column"><input style="width:100%"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="first-column">label</td>
      <td class="second-column"><input style="width:100%"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    
  
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td class="first-column">medium label</td>
      <td class="second-column"><input style="width:100%"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="first-column">label</td>
      <td class="second-column"><input style="width:100%"/></td>
    </tr>
 </table>

 <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td class="first-column">label</td>
      <td class="second-column"><input style="width:100%"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="first-column">label</td>
      <td class="second-column"><input style="width:100%"/></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

I need the first column to be sized by it's content (width of the longest label), but in case of very long labels it should not fill more then 50% of table.
Something like this
[image]

Could you please help me to write correct css for this case? I can't use Javascript, it should be css-only solution.

Comment: .first-column{ max-width: 50%; width: 100%; } - https://jsfiddle.net/b84yhvt3/1/

Comment: in second table first column width is 50%, and I need it to be by content

Comment: See my example - https://jsfiddle.net/9jmwf5kc/

Comment: The fiddle from @LuisP.A. gives the right visual result but it requires the system to know in advance which are the short columns (and introduces a no-wrap for those). Are you constrained to using a table rather than some other HTML structure?

Comment: @AHaworth no, I don't have constraints to use only table element. I just need table layout. It can be made with any other html elements.

Comment: @АрсенМирзаян: if you need to have variable widths on the 'label' columns, but all column widths within the same table must have the same width, there's a good chance that CSS grid might work for you. But will your back-end always put long, medium and short labels in the same table, or could a table exist with both short and long labels? Would that be a problem for you, what should happen?

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, this is the case. Table has multiple rows with different label widths, short: medim and long. I need first column to fit the longest label but not more then 50% of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own suggestion for this would be to firstly – unless this is impractical for other reasons – consolidate all your label and `<input>` elements into the same parent-element, which simplifies the alignment of all columns.

To this end I've grouped the elements into a single `<fieldset>` element, itself within a `<form>`:

```js
// This JavaScript has no part to play in the resizing of elements,
// but merely logs the size of each of the two columns in the
// relevant elements (the last <label> and the last <input>:
const D = document,
            logLengths = () => {
    let label = D.querySelector('label:last-of-type'),
        input = D.querySelector('input:last-of-type');
  [label, input].forEach(
    (el) =>{
        el[ 
        el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input' ? 'value' : 'textContent'
        ] = Math.round(el.getBoundingClientRect().width*10)/10 + 'px';
    });
};

logLengths();
D.querySelectorAll('label').forEach(
    (label) => label.addEventListener('input', logLengths)
);
```

```css
/* Generic CSS reset: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  /* using CSS logical properties to place a 1em margin
     on the block axis (top/bottom) in left-to-right, top-
     to-bottom languages) */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* ...and a margin of auto (to centre the element) on
     the inline-axis (left and right in ltr languages): */
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 0.2em;
  width: 90vw;
}

fieldset {
  /* in order to use CSS Grid: */
  display: grid;
  /* setting gaps/'gutters' between rows of 0.5em,
     and 0.25em gaps between adjacent columns: */
  gap: 0.5em 0.25em;
  /* defining two columns, the first of which is sized
     'auto', allowing the layout to be sized appropriately
     to the content within the limits of other columns,
     the second column is sized using the 'minmax()'
     function between a minimum size of 50% (because the
     maximum permitted size of the first column is 50%),
     and 1fr, which is the fractional unit of the remaining
     space available: */
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(50%, 1fr);
}

/* this styles the 'information' <div> that provides
   guidance about the interactivity of the editable
   <label> elements: */
fieldset div {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

code, kbd {
  font-family: consolas, ubuntu mono, monospace;
}

kbd {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  padding: 0.1em 0.3em;
}

label {
  /* to indicate interactivity: */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* for positioning the pseudo element: */
  position: relative;
}

/* entirely irrelevant to the demo, but just to
   make it look a little prettier (adjust to
   taste or remove as you like): */
label::before {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, lime, #ffff);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

label:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.length {
  background: revert;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid currentColor;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
  <!-- this <div> is here simply to provide some guidance as to the
       interactivity of the <label> elements for the purpose of this
       demo; otherwise it can be removed entirely: -->
  <div>Most labels are <code>contentEditable</code>, though they will focus the &lt;input&gt; element when clicked; <kbd>shift</kbd>&plus;<kbd>tab</kbd> to focus the &lt;label&gt;</div>
    <!-- because we're using a grid (and the majority of browsers don't yet
         support display: subgrid) to create the aligned columns, the <input>
         elements are the following-siblings of the <label> elements; in order
         to associate the <label> with the correct <input> I've added an 'id'
         attribute to each <input>, and the same id-value for the associated
         <label> in their 'for' attribute; this means clicking/tapping on a
         <label> will focus the appropriate <input>: -->
    <label for="inputElement_0" contentEditable>longer label</label>
    <input id="inputElement_0">
    <label for="inputElement_1" contentEditable>label</label>
    <input id="inputElement_1">
    <label for="inputElement_2" contentEditable>medium label</label>
    <input id="inputElement_2">
    <label for="inputElement_3" contentEditable>label</label>
    <input id="inputElement_3">
    <label for="inputElement_4" contentEditable>label</label>
    <input id="inputElement_4">
    <label for="inputElement_5" contentEditable>label</label>
    <input id="inputElement_5">
    <!-- these elements are here purely to report the length of the 
         grid-columns in which they appear: -->
    <label for="lengthInput" class="length"></label>
    <input id="lengthInput" type="text" class="length" readonly>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n4shr0j1/3).

If subgrid is available in your browser (currently it's only available in Firefox), then the following is possible:

```js
// Again, this JavaScript has nothing to do with the resizing, but only shows
// the widths of the grid-tracks the elements are in:
const D = document,
  logLengths = () => {
    let label = D.querySelector('label:last-of-type'),
      input = label.querySelector('input:last-of-type');
    [label, input].forEach(
      (el) => {
        let width = Math.round(el.getBoundingClientRect().width / 10) * 10,
          val = `${width}px`;
        if (el.matches('label')) {
          label.firstChild.nodeValue = val;
        } else if (el.matches('input')) {
          el.value = val;
        }
      });
  };

logLengths();
D.querySelectorAll('label').forEach(
  (label) => label.addEventListener('input', logLengths)
);
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 0.2em;
  width: 90vw;
}

fieldset {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em 0.25em;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(50%, 1fr);
}

fieldset div {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

code,
kbd {
  font-family: consolas, ubuntu mono, monospace;
}

kbd {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  padding: 0.1em 0.3em;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  /* Using display: grid to allow us to make use
     of subgrid: */
  display: grid;
  /* instructing the layout engine to use the
     grid-columns/grid-tracks of the parent
     element: */
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  /* positioning the grid-start in the first
     grid-column and the grid-end in the last
     grid-column: */
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, lime, #ffff);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

label:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.length {
  background: revert;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid currentColor;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <div>All labels are <code>contentEditable</code>, though they will focus the &lt;input&gt; element when clicked; <kbd>shift</kbd>&plus;<kbd>tab</kbd> to focus the &lt;label&gt;</div>
    <!-- because we can use subgrid, we can place the <input> elements
         inside of their associated <label> elements, which removes the
         need to assign either a 'for' attribute to the <label> or an
         'id' attribute to the <input>, since they're automatically
         associated this way via nesting: -->
    <label contentEditable>longer label
      <input>
    </label>

    <label contentEditable>label
      <input>
    </label>
    <label contentEditable>medium label
      <input>
    </label>
    <label contentEditable>label
      <input>
    </label>
    <label contentEditable>label
      <input>
    </label>
    <label contentEditable>label
      <input>
    </label>
    <label class="length">
      <input type="text" class="length" readonly>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n4shr0j1/4/).

References:

- HTML

  - [`contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable).
- CSS:

  - [CSS `<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).
  - [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`:last-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type).
  - [`minmax()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax()).
  - [`subgrid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).
  - [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: If I remove in very long label your first code snippet then label's column still takes 50% of the grid. https://jsfiddle.net/dw26gj3p/

Comment: @АрсенМирзаян: I've just updated the demos; my mistake was misunderstanding the `minmax()` function; in this demo most of the `<label>` elements are `contentEditable`, and allow you to enter or remove text to demonstrate the resizing live. My apologies, I thought I'd checked that the original code worked as expected before posting. *Sigh...* Also, while there is some JavaScript in the answer that plays no part in the resizing, just in reporting the current size of each of the grid-tracks.

Comment: perfect. It works exactly as I need. Thank you for your help. I mark this answer as solution.

Comment: @АрсенМирзаян: you're very welcome, I'm glad to have helped!

Answer (score -1):

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
td.first-column {
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
  <td class="first-column">very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very label</td>
  <td class="second-column"><input style="width:100%"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
  <td class="first-column">short label</td>
  <td class="second-column"><input style="width:100%"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not working. I pressed "Run code snippet" and result is not as expected.

Comment: After editing answer it's not working, beacuse in the second table first column size is 50%, while I need width by content.

Comment: ah, now I get it. I will look on it bit later